# Symlink behavior with Dropbox on Windows

Tags: windows, dropbox, symbolic-link

Does Dropbox still sync symlinked *content* on Windows? The documentation suggests it shouldn't, but I think it currently still does.

#### Documentation

Per this [Dropbox Article](https://help.dropbox.com/installs-integrations/sync-uploads/symlinks), Dropbox no longer syncs symlinks.

> As of mid-2019, Dropbox no longer follows items outside of your Dropbox account that are linked to by a symlink.
>
> [...]
>
> If you create a symlink that links to an item outside of your Dropbox account, when you sign in to dropbox.com you’ll only see the symlink file but not the content it links to

#### Reproducing the Issue

However, this description does not seem to apply to Windows, either for symlinks pointing to files or folders.

```
# in "C:\Users\vince\Desktop", outside my Dropbox
# I created the file `foo.txt` 
# I also created the folder `quas` containing the file `wex.txt`

C:\Windows\system32>cd "C:\Users\vince\Dropbox"

C:\Users\vince\Dropbox>mklink bar.txt "C:\Users\vince\Desktop\foo.txt"
symbolic link created for bar.txt <<===>> C:\Users\vince\Desktop\foo.txt

C:\Users\vince\Dropbox>mklink /D exort "C:\Users\vince\Desktop\quas"
symbolic link created for exort <<===>> C:\Users\vince\Desktop\quas

# files synced to Dropbox still contain symlinked content, rather than simply being symlinks.
```

#### OS and Version Details

I'm using Microsoft Windows 10 Home. I currently have Dropbox v87.4.138 installed.

#### Background

I'm interested in understanding how symlinks interact with Dropbox because I'm trying to address a situation where I would like only some content in a folder to be synced.

Specifically, in a Dropbox folder `bar`, I have a file (`foo.lrcat`) that I want synced and a folder (`foo Previews.lrdata`) containing content that I don't want synced (because the folder is large and has content that changes often). The program I'm using (Lightroom) requires that the `foo.lrcat` and `foo Previews.lrdata` be in the same folder.

Depending on the expected behavior in Dropbox, I'd do one of the following:

1. If Dropbox syncs symlinked content, I would move `bar` out of Dropbox and create a symlink to `foo.lrcat` from within Dropbox.
2. If Dropbox does not sync symlinked content, I would move `foo Previews.lrdata` out of Dropbox and create a symlink from within `bar` to that folder so that Lightroom still has access to the information.

Comment: Provided the link won't be on a different drive, would a hardlink still work?

Comment: I can try that, but how would a hardlink help in this particular case?

Comment: Because it's not a symlink... symlinks and hardlinks are two different things.

Comment: I added a bit of background to explain why I'm interested in understanding how Dropbox interacts with symlinks. Hope it all makes a bit more sense now.